# Fetching data from json file into Nodejs (Protractor code)

Tags: protractor

I have 2 files. First one is JSON which contain all the data. Second is Js file where code is written and the data should be fetched from JSON file. But its unable to take the dta from JSON file. My JSON file name is Sampledata.json and the content is:

```
[{
      'Test_URL':'http:...........',
      'User_Name':'xyz',
      'Password': 'abc'
}]
```

My Js code is :

```
var Sampledata = require('E:\\Sampledata.json');
console.log("Check the sample data",  Sampledata);
describe('Open the clinicare website by logging into the site', function(){
    it('Should Add a text in username and password fields and hit login button', function() {

        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //console.log(Sampledata.Test_URL);

       browser.get(Sampledata.Test_URL); 

        //Perform Login:UserName 
        element(by.model('accessCode')).sendKeys(Sampledata.User_Name); 

        //Perform Login:Password 
        element(by.model('password')).sendKeys(Sampledata.Password); 

        //Perform Login:LoginButton 
        element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right')).click(); 
  });
});
```

If anyone can help me out in this will be very helpful for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am getting the below error while I am running the code:     
  E:\>protractor conf1.js
(node:24980) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[12:18:40] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:18:40] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:18:44] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.212.134.201:55329/wd/hub
[12:18:54] E/launcher - Error: SyntaxError: E:\Sampledata.json: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 24

Answer (score 0):

You have not a single JSON, but array of JSONS.

Try:
`Sampledata[0].Test_URL` instead of `Sampledata.Test_URL`.

Same with `Sampledata.User_Name`, `Sampledata.Password`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kacper for the help. It was very helhful for me.